# Generate Signed APK rx.java error

Tags: android, google-play, apk, proguard, android-signing

I want to add my project to Play Store so I want to make Signed APK for this. But I'm taking this error.

[image]

Then I add to proguard-rules `-dontwarn rx.internal.util.unsafe.**` .Then I'm able to create signed APK. I added to Play Store this Signed APK but Play Store give me error `This Apk is not signed`.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: check this  https://github.com/artem-zinnatullin/RxJavaProGuardRules  change proguard rules